# Having trouble with concatenating two strings

Tags: php, mysql

I've been tossing and turning around why on earth this thing won't work.
The two strings won't combine and only the $title will be saved. How come? :(
even if the account is admin, it won't work. The value of account that will be saved is admin and yet the title wont concatenate. :(

See the code for yourself

```
    <?php

    $con    = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("fullcalendar", $con);

    $title  = $_POST['title'];
    $start  = $_POST['start'];
    $end    = $_POST['end'];
    $account= $_POST['account'];
    $sumpay = 'USC' ;

       if($account == "admin")
       {
         $ti= $title.$sumpay;
       }

    // insert the records
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evenement");
    mysql_query( "INSERT INTO evenement (id, title, start, end, account) 
        VALUES ('', '$ti', '$start', '$end' , '$account')");
    ?>
```

Comment: What var_dump($_POST); does show?

Comment: If `$account` is not equal to `admin`, then the `$ti` variable is undefined. You never defined it before...

Comment: Take care: you are using an outdated and deprecated db connector. Consider porting the the newer and more secure `mysqli` db connector or `PDO` and read about "prepared statements". You current code leaves you wide open to sql injections, so it is very vulnerable and insecure.

Comment: An sql injection might actually be the cause of your problems. What is the value of `$title`?

Comment: Oh, and another thing: those VALUES inside your statements should either have double quote chars (`"`) or none at all.

Comment: It's still offline guys and I tried using the mysqli and still no changes. :(

Comment: @arkascha the value is user input and it just depends. :(

Comment: @arkascha I tried changing the single qoutes to double qoutes but still nothing man. :(

Comment: Sorry, actual my comment about the double quotes was complete nonsense.

Comment: About the user input: that is exactly the problem. You have no idea what _might_ be contained in there. This is why you have to take precaution which your current code does not do at all. That is why I mentioned those terms above. You really should start reading to understand what the problem is. One hint: how will your statement look like if the user input contains a `'`?

Answer (score 0):

try using [mysqli...](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)

```
 //   first check the values posted using
   print_r($_POST);
```

also make this change...

```
   if($account == "admin")
     $ti= $title.$sumpay;
   else
     $ti= $title;
```

Comment: whats the result of  `print_r($_POST);`